# Видео блокирует запуск js кода

Tags: javascript, html, видео

Проблема такая, на сайте есть видео которые вставлены с помощью тега video, из-за этого js включается через 15-20 секунд, есть предположение что на это влияет загрузка видео, скрипты подключаются снизу страницы, подскажите если предполжение верное, что можно сделать?

Comment: тут зависит от того, как вставляется видео, как вставляется script. Пример был бы очень кстати!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перенести скрипт вверх страницы и добавить атрибут defer. Работает только с внешними скриптами.

Пример: `<script defer src="script.js"></script>`